# Why should I remove the old managed object model from source control?

Tags: git, core-data, version-control, xcode4

on [this apple documentation page](http://file:///Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.4_2.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/converting_model_to_versioned.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH12-SW1) (4.2 installed docs... currently need beta to see) they end "If you are using a source version control system such as Subversion, ensure that the old model file is removed from your repository, and the new model directory and files are added to your repository." I feel like I must not understand what they mean. If I removed it from my repository, I couldn't roll back to an old version of my app, no?

Something about this just breaks in my mind. If they have separate name, why should I mess around with how git tracks them?

I guess I have two questions, what should I do, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is likely because Subversion works at the folder level and, since a versioned MOM file is actually a package (a folder that acts like a single file), Xcode's conversion process likely breaks an SVN repo by outright replacing the single MOM file with a versioned MOM file *package*.

Xcode takes a To "do it right", they'd have to do a lot of extra work with your working copy if you're using SVN. I think this will probably work fine with a Git repo (considering you tagged this with Git). Make a backup copy and give it a try with Git. With "others" (especially Subversion), you'll pretty much have to follow those instructions since a MOM "folder" will be replaced rather than modified.

As far as version history goes, it's still just a revision and you'd be able to revert to it anyway. Obviously you wouldn't be able to use a visual diff tool as easily as with a simple source file change, but how often do you visually diff a managed object model?

Comment: Just updated with more precise info. I left out details that made it technically wrong. Incidentally, your link points to a local installed copy of 4.2 documentation, which not everyone has yet. :-)